# Altering the colour of Vimeo player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vimeo

Far I've found that giving the iframe a background colour will alter the timeline number colour, but other than that I'm not seeing a way to change the player's controls colour other than the Vimeo embed code itself.

```
... iframe { background-color: #000; }
```

I'd Google'd this quite a bit, not found anything unfortunately so I turn to stack. I'm looking to change player controls. I have a slight feeling this can be done with jQuery maybe? Grab the default colour and change it, or something would be the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said it can be achieved with [options in Vimeo's embed code](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player).

Alternatively, use those embed options to enable the Javascript API with `api=1` then you can [change options and set the color via Javascript](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js) with `setColor()`.

Vimeo are [working on an embeddable HTML5 player](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:21871) in which case you'll have full control over the player controls.

Hope that helps

Comment: Via the link, I don't see any option to change the background color, only the player controls color.